# AngularJS minification controllers not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, google-closure-compiler

I'm using [closure-compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler) to minify the javascript for my angular app. The app.config, app.run, and main app controller all work fine. However, none of the other controllers are working, they are all undefined (angular.min.js:118 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=ContactCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined).

The controllers are all using dependency injection for anything I need to access in them, so I don't think that's the problem. Here's an example of the definition for one of my controllers:

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', 'requestService',
function ContactCtrl($scope, requestService) { // stuff here }]);
```

And I use ui-router to switch states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'js/components/home/home.html'
    })
    .state('feature', {
        url: '/feature',
        templateUrl: 'js/components/feature/feature.html',
        controller: 'FeatureCtrl',
    });
```

I also have another controller that is declared in the html:

```
<div data-ng-include="'js/components/home/contact.html'" data-ng-controller="ContactCtrl"></div>
```

Is there some sort of dependency injection I need to do for Controllers as well? Or should I just use some other minification library? I like this one because I can just execute the jar by pointing to a directory and telling it to minify all js into one file, all in one quick command:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js_output_file=out.js in1.js in2.js in3.js ...
```

Also it's made by Google so I would think it should work with Angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Closure Compiler with AngularJS in ADVANCED\_MODE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776460/use-closure-compiler-with-angularjs-in-advanced-mode)

Comment: I have a controller in the <html> tag as the main controller for my app. This controller works just fine, I'm passing in $rootScope, $scope, $state, $timeout and all this works. The problem is with my other controllers, they are not being found for some reason.

Comment: Where are the other controllers written? Are you including the JavaScript (.js) file where you have written these controllers?

Comment: I have all my controllers defined in different files, separated in different directories. However, I just looked at the minified output from closure-compiler, and it is only including js files in the top level directory, even though I'm using the 'app/**.js' option in the command. so for some reason it is not recursively looking through subdirectories for my other js files.

Comment: What compilation mode?